# twilio video in incognito window is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-video

Hello i am trying to create a video chat application with twilio video in javascript. the problem i had is when i enter the url in incognito window  the video is not working but in normal chrome window it works great.

i get video the code from get(https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) with that i just adjust css and add my socket.io chat

So i inspect in incognito window in console

```
he AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture 
on the page. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#webaudio
```

and i allow permissions in incognito window

i even create another page to see my video and audio it works great in incognito window

code

```
const videobox = document.querySelector('.box-video');
            const myVideo = document.createElement('video');

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video:true,
                audio:true,
            }).then((stream)=>{
                     addvideo(myVideo,stream);
            })

            function addvideo(video,stram) {
                video.srcObject = stram;
                video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',()=>{
                    video.play()
                })
                videobox.append(video);
            }
```

Anyone have any idea what went wrong.

Comment: Have you changed how the user enters the room? I just got the application running and when I load it in an incognito window I am asked what room to join and my user name. When I click "join" I then successfully join the room. That click is the user gesture that the error is asking for and the quickstart app handles resuming the audio. So have you changed anything like that?

Comment: @philnash No, i did not change

Comment: So, the app doesn't work for you when you open it in incognito mode, fill in the room and user name and press join?

Comment: @philnash Yes, the app doesn't work for me when i open it in incognito mode

Comment: OK, I think we need to dig deeper into what is happening. What doesn't work exactly? Are there other logs in the dev tools?

Comment: @philnash i don't know what happen, but now it works great in incognito mode ,thanks for your time

Comment: Great to hear it!